# A C* algebra admitting a predual is isomorphic to a von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Consider the following Theorem:

> A $C^*$-algebra is $*$-isomorphic to a von Neumann algebra iff it is the dual of a Banach space.

The direction "von Neumann algebras have preduals" is clear to me, however I cannot find a proper reference for the other direction. In the book by Bratteli and Robinson it is remarked that this is proven in Theorem 1.16.7. in Sakai's paper [On the central decomposition for positive functionals on *-algebras](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-central-decomposition-for-positive-on-Sakai/5fe0fdb66299f45c86eb38519725a4365208231e). However this Theorem doesn't exist in the paper and the paper is about something completely different, so I think they intended to reference another paper.

Where can one find a proof of the other direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof for the direction which you are looking for can be found as the proof of Theorem 1.16.7 in Sakai's book [$C^*$-Algebras and $W^\ast$-Algebras](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540636335).

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}$